# Header Separation

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a header, something like this:

```
Unix Linux Trumpet Perl 1|1 1|2 1|3
```

How can I change the header into something like this:

```
                          1   1   1
Unix Linux Trumpet Perl   1   2   3
```

I tried using a for loop:

```
awk 'for (i=0; 1<row.length; i++)
if values[i] == "|"
```

Then split the row and append it in the same column but it's not working. How can I do this on Linux?

Answer (score 0):

One way:

```
$ cat file 
Unix Linux Trumpet Perl 1|1 1|2 1|3
$
$ awk -F"[ |]" '{
 printf "%-10s %-10s %-10s %-10s %-3s %-3s %-3s\n","","","","",$5,$7,$9;
 printf "%-10s %-10s %-10s %-10s %-3s %-3s %-3s\n",$1,$2,$3,$4,$6,$8,$10;
 }' file
                                            1   1   1
Unix       Linux      Trumpet    Perl       1   2   3
```